# Sequencing IO actions in parallel

Tags: haskell, io, parallel-processing

I have a function that returns an IO action,

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
```

I would like to compute this function in parallel for multiple values of the argument. My naive implementation was as follows:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

vals = [1..10]
main = do
      results <- mapM f vals
      let results' = results `using` parList rseq
      mapM_ print results'
```

My reasoning for this was that the first `mapM` binds something of type `IO [Int]` to `results`, `results'` applies a parallel strategy to the contained list, and the `mapM_` finally requests the actual values by printing them - but what is to be printed is already sparked in parallel, so the program should parallelize.

After being happy that it does indeed use all my CPUs, I noticed that the program is less effective (as in wall clock time) when being run with `+RTS -N8` than without any RTS flags. The only explanation I can think of is that the first `mapM` has to sequence - i.e. perform - all the IO actions already, but that would not lead to ineffectivity, but make the `N8` execution as effective as the unparallelized one, because all the work is done by the master thread. Running the program with `+RTS -N8 -s` yields `SPARKS: 36 (11 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 21 GC'd, 4 fizzled)`, which surely isn't optimal, but unfortunately I can't make any sense of it.

I suppose I've found one of the beginner's stepping stones in Haskell parallelization or the internals of the IO monad. What am I doing wrong?

Background info: `f n` is a function that returns the solution for Project Euler problem n. Since many of them have data to read, I put the result into the IO monad. An example of how it may look like is

```
-- Problem 13: Work out the first ten digits of the sum of one-hundred 50-digit numbers.

euler 13 = fmap (first10 . sum) numbers
      where
            numbers = fmap (map read . explode '\n') $ readFile "problem_13"
            first10 n
                  | n < 10^10 = n -- 10^10 is the first number with 11 digits
                  | otherwise  = first10 $ n `div` 10
```

The full file can be found [here](http://codepad.org/VYXqTeQh) (It's a bit long, but the first few "euler X" functions should be representative enough), the main file where I do the parallelism is [this one](http://codepad.org/ehLwYrjL).

Comment: That's hard to diagnose without seeing more. If you run it with `+RTS -s -N`, what are the stats of converted/pruned/fizzled sparks? And does `f n` return a thunk that can actually be sparked?

Comment: @DanielFischer I was a bit hesitant posting the full file because it's quite long (minimal examples and such). I thought my mistake was in the parallel code, so I focused on that in my question. I've now added a new paragraph, and also the `-s` statistics (which are awful).

Comment: I'm not sure whether the ones actually doing I/O would destroy it, but for the pure ones (not using `Data.Permute`, since I don't have that installed), I got a speedup (and more converted sparks) using `parListChunk k` instead of `parList` - even with `parListChunk 1`, although that calls `parList`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I noticed as well that chunked parallelism is faster. In any case, now I'm not only interested in how to make my program run faster, but also in why exactly it doesn't work already :-)

Answer (score 8):

Strategies are for parallel execution of pure computations. If it really is mandatory that your `f` returns an `IO` value, then consider using the `async` package instead. It provides useful combinators for running `IO` actions concurrently.

For your use case, `mapConcurrently` looks useful:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async

vals = [1..10]
main = do
  results <- mapConcurrently f vals
  mapM_ print results
```

(I haven't tested though, because I don't know what your `f` is exactly.)

Comment: If you *want* to test it, I've added the full script at the end of my post. If not: Async suffers from the same performance hit, but it's a package that looks very promising that I've neglected so far, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Try the `parallel-io` package.  It allows you to change any `mapM_` into `parallel_`.